# Intel Thread Building Blocks (TBB) in google native client (NaCl, PNaCl)

Tags: opencv, intel, tbb, google-nativeclient

The current google native client port of OpenCV does not utilise TBB. It says [here](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEAQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Fpubs%2Farchive%2F34913.pdf&ei=uiKFVKb6D8GC8gXu1III&usg=AFQjCNEEM1t1Iv_Fsfzom5g3a2fUaAuyMA&bvm=bv.80642063,d.dGc) TBB can be built under NaCl.

Is there an official port, or has anyone successfully built TBB under NaCl?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now there is no official port of Intel TBB for NaCl, and the project team at Intel (which I work in) is unaware of any unofficial one either.